# Price Difference In List.phtml and View.Phtml in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, list.phtml

I have a magento store running on magento 1.9 version which has 30000+ products. When i update a product and apply a rule it has to be reindexed to apply the rule. **And whenever i do that ,there will be a price difference on the List view and Product view before the reindex completes.List view shows the wrong value but the Product page displays correct Price**. I have gone through the List.phtml and view.phtml in the path html\app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\template\catalog\product . 
In list.phtml

```
"<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>" 

and in view.phtml it is 

"<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>".
```

My question is, is that difference in the price is just because of that additional "true" parsed in List.phtml or something else. If it is not that what is the solution??Which is the database are these files are fetching the price value from?? And where exactly i find(Path for the file) that query to make both files to fetch from same database table?

Answer (score 1):

Please go to **index management** and **re-index**.It will automatically  update the database table.

I hope it will help you,Thanks.

Comment: i want you read the bold part of my question. The problem exist when i keep for reindexing. So i would like to have a uniform price in both list and product pages. It would be better if you tell me where exactly i can find the query connecting to database of list and view page respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that on the product list page, the product data is coming from the catalog flat table, and on the product view page the data is coming from the catalog_product_entity_* tables. The second parameter in the getPriceHtml function is whether or not to display the "As Low As" text next to the price.

Comment: can you please tell me where i can find the file which is calling catalog flat table for list view and the same for the product view page.